# org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: No modal dialog is currently open

Tags: java, selenium

I'm writing a small piece of code to automate a daily task. As part of this task I login into our internal website and click on a specific tab which prompts a dialog box where i need to click on yes or no to disable. I used an alert statement but it still throws the below error. Also I'm doing this for the first time in my career. Never done this before. Can anyone please help me with this ?

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: No modal dialog is currently open

**My code:**

```
package test;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class automate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\405325\\eclipse-workspace\\Monitoring\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.mywebsite.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("myusername");
        driver.findElement(By.name("passWord")).sendKeys("mypassword");
        driver.findElement(By.name("loginForm")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tabIndent\"]/div/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/a/font")).click();

        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dialog20HideableContent\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/form/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td")).click();

    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like the dialog box is not a standard alert box. Is it an html element which is made visible? Check and inspect the source

Comment: All the pop-up messages may not be alerts. If the application is developed using recent UI frameworks like bootstrap or AngularJs, Div's can also be displayed like alert messages. So check your page source, the alert may be enclosed in div tag. If its div you can directly write the code to click on the button (this is also element), you don't need to switch to alert.

Comment: Remove the `Alert` line... now does it work? Sounds like the alert isn't a JS alert. One quick way to determine if it is an alert is to right-click on the popup. If you get the standard context menu, it's HTML and not an alert. Right-clicking on an alert will not bring up a context menu. Treat the HTML dialog just like any other HTML. You might need to add a wait to ensure that the HTML dialog has fully loaded before interacting with it.

Comment: Hi as per above recommendations i was able to figure out that the pop up is also an HTML and now i have used the find element thing but it still throws an error. The problem is that the xpath and the id keep changing for this html constantly. new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dialog20HideableContent\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/form/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td"))).click();

Comment: error that im getting now is Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: looks like its not able find the xpath as it is generating new xpath everytime

Answer (score 0):

As per you question, your code trials and error you are seeing it appears that the **dialog box** is a **Modal Dialog Box** and to invoke `click()` on it you have to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dialog20HideableContent\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/form/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td"))).click();
```